# .NET SyncLock order deadlock

Tags: vb.net, deadlock, synclock

If I have two Synclocks

```
synclock a
  synclock b
  end synclock
end synclock
```

am I in danger of a deadlock if I never have

```
synclock b
  synclock a
  end synclock
end synclock
```

in my code, but I do synclock on a or b randomly?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you always lock a before b then you'll be okay.

Comment: True, but what I'm wondering is, if a is always locked from function 1 and b is always locked from function 2 and the synclock a,b is in function 3 and each function is running on different thread, will I still be ok?

Comment: The hard-to-see case is code that only locks b, then goes off inside some deeply nested code that locks a.